# How to compare string with specific part of array item?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array arr[] of string type with array-items as follows:

```
arr[0]= "2/13/2019|202"
arr[1]= "2/14/2019|197"
arr[2]= "2/15/2019|101"
arr[4]= "2/16/2019|271"
arr[5]= "2/17/2019|199"
```

I want to get an array-item that matches my string "2/15/2019" so I can get "2/15/2019|101".
in short, I just want to compare my string with the array-item string till "|" and rest strong will not be considered for comparison.
how can I get it?

Comment: use contains() method

Comment: `var results = arr.Where(x => x.StartsWith("2/15/2019"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use where and contains

```
           string getdata = "2/15/2019";
            string[] arr = new string[5];
            arr[0] = "2/13/2019|202";
            arr[1] = "2/14/2019|197";
            arr[2] = "2/15/2019|101";
            arr[3] = "2/16/2019|271";
            arr[4] = "2/17/2019|199";

            var op = arr.Where(a => a.Contains(getdata)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq to get the data you are looking for.

- use Contains(string) to check if there is one or more elements that match your criteria
- if it does, get the first one from the list (or you can assign that list to a variable and iterate through each of it)
- Split the value and get the value after |
- Use `?.` after `FirstOrDefault()` method to ensure you dont get NullReferenceException when you run `Split()`.
- Use validation to ensure result is not null.

```
var result = arr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("2/15/2019"))?.Split('|')[1];
// result contains 101
```

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8): Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found

Comment: just need to remove?

Comment: @devSS If you use `?.` before `Split`, you wont get Null Reference exceptions if there is no element in the array that contains that string. Try a search with string that doesnt match. `?.` ensures there is always a value to run split on without exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) and [`StartWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var results = arr.Where(x => x.StartsWith("2/15/2019"));
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

[String.StartsWith Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8)

> Determines whether the beginning of this string instance matches a
>   specified string.